# Unable to inject factory into test suite using Karma/Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, django, karma-jasmine

I have an Angular app with a Django back end. I am just starting with Karma and Jasmine unit testing. I am unable to inject my factory into my test suite. Is there any suggestions or glaring errors that I am making?

***Here are my files...***

***karma.conf.js file***

```
module.exports = function(config) {
config.set({

basePath: '',

frameworks: ['jasmine'],

files: [
    './node_modules/angular/angular.js',                             
    './node_modules/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js', 
    './node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js', 
    './fake/path/fake/js/directory/src/modules.js',
    './fake/path/fake/js/directory/src/factories/projectinfostorage.js',
    './fake/path/fake/js/directory/src/factories/projectinfostorage.spec.js',
],

exclude: [
],

preprocessors: {
},

reporters: ['progress'],

port: 9876,

colors: true,

logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,

autoWatch: true,

browsers: ['Chrome'],

singleRun: false,

concurrency: Infinity
})
}
```

***Angular module...***

```
var app = angular.module("tablebrowser", ["ngRoute"]);
```

***Factory...***

```
app.factory('projectInfoStorage', function(){
    var factory = {};

    return factory;
})
```

***Factory Unit Test...***

```
describe('projectInfoStorage factory', function() {
      var projectInfoStorage;

      beforeEach(angular.mock.module('tablebrowser'));

      beforeEach(inject(function(_projectInfoStorage_) {
          projectInfoStorage = _projectInfoStorage_;
      }));

      console.log(projectInfoStorage)
  });
```

***Karma shows me this in the command line...***

```
Chrome 55.0.2883 (Mac OS X 10.10.5) LOG: undefined

Chrome 55.0.2883 (Mac OS X 10.10.5): Executed 0 of 0 SUCCEChrome 55.0.2883     (Mac OS X 10.10.5): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0 secs / 0 secs)
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason your test doesn't work is because you haven't actually tested anything.  Within that describe function you need to actually put the test in an it function.  Something like below:

```
describe('projectInfoStorage factory', function() {
    var projectInfoStorage;

    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('tablebrowser'));

    beforeEach(inject(function(_projectInfoStorage_) {
        projectInfoStorage = _projectInfoStorage_;
    }));

    it('will test factory', function() {
        expect(true).toBeTruthy();
    }
});
```

You need to build your tests with these in order to test something.

Comment: beforeEach runs before each test - you have no tests, so beforeEach never runs